# It is okay to set MASQUERADE at 2 network interfaces in a Linux server?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, ip-forwarding, masquerade

There is a Linux server with 3 network interfaces, `eth0, eth1, eth2`. IP forwarding has been turn on in this server.

1. eth0 is connected to 10.0.1.0/24. Its IP is `10.0.1.1`.
2. eth1 is connected to 172.16.1.0/24. Its IP is `172.16.1.1`. Server A can ping router C at 172.16.1.2.
3. eth2 is connected to 192.168.1.0/24. Its IP is `192.168.1.1`. Server A can ping server B at 192.168.1.2.
4. Router C is able to route to 172.16.2.0/24 and 172.16.3.0/24.

```
                                          [10.0.1.0/24]
                                                |
172.16.2.0/24------|                            |
                   [C]------172.16.1.0/24------[A]------192.168.1.0/24------[B]
172.16.3.0/24------|
```

We have set MASQUERADE at eth0. When server B (192.168.1.2) connect to 10.0.1.0/24, IP MASQUERADE will happen at eth0.

Can we set MASQUERADE at eth1? Is it okay to set MASQUERADE at more than 1 network interfaces in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to have multiple `MASQUERADE` rules.  Typically, each rule will match packets going out a specific interface, for example:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

The first rule matches packets going out `eth0`, while the second one matches packets going out `eth1`.